# How can I index rebuild on multiple table every day at 3 AM efficient way?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-administration

I run below command on multiple tables but is it right way to do index rebuild or is there any better way to do it every day at specified time using event?
OPTIMIZE TABLE table1, table2;

My second question is that, if another process(insert,delete,update) run on same table during index rebuild then what will happen for that process?

Is process same for both MariaDB, MySQL?

Since I am working on those DBMS that is why I need to know the actual behavior in this scenario.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: *is it right way to do index rebuild* This rebuilds the whole table, including indices rebuilding. Clear separate index rebuilding cannot be performed in MySQL. The simplest and fastest way to do this is index droping and recreation. *Is process same for both MariaDB, MySQL?* Yes. *if another process(insert,delete,update) run on same table during index rebuild then what will happen for that process?* OPTIMIZE TABLE is performed online for regular and partitioned InnoDB tables. Otherwise, MySQL locks the table during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ENGINE=InnoDB` (on MySQL or MariaDB), there is "never" any need to rebuild indexes or do `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Sure, either will do some "defragmentation", but, because of the way BTrees work, they become fragmented promptly.  And, a fragmented BTree is only slightly slower.

Read and write operations are interfered with by anything that will rebuild an index -- another argument against periodic rebuilding.

About the only useful time to use `OPTIMIZE` is after you have `DELETEd` most of a table.  In that situation, I have a list of better ways to do the big delete.

Comment: Moderators,  Surely you know OPTIMIZE is more than useful.  A table 3 years old with added rows scattered in the blocks will be surely fragmented and NEED to be OPTIMIZED.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - InnoDB will merge two adjacent blocks that are are under half full.  (Or at least that is what they say.)

Comment: The half full is hard code or?  If it's useless,  mysql should not provide this command to confuse the user.

Comment: @SeanH - Yeah, there are a lot of left-over commands from when MyISAM was the only Engine.  I had 2 cases in MyISAM where a _monthly_ `OPTIMIZE` on specific tables was useful.  In InnoDB, the only use case is after heavy deletes.  But if you expect heavy deleting, there are better ways to do it; they will both speed up the deletion and eliminate most/all of the fragmentation.